# How to add global preinclude files to a QtCreator project?

Tags: c, qt-creator, qmake

For unit test purposes, I need to add a include file (e.g. `header.h`) to a Qt Creator project, which will be preincluded for every c-file. GCC supports this via `-include header.h` in `CFLAGS`.

In Qt Creator, I haven't been able to find a solution for this. Putting the include directive to `QMAKE_CFLAGS` has no effect.

I found many hints about adding global include paths (that's not my purpose), but nothing about global preinclude files.

Comment: Note that your solution is restricted to GCC on Linux/Mac/MinGW/Cygwin/BSD, and won't work for MSVC (and Clang-cl), which needs [`/FI`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c5ztk84.aspx).

Comment: @rubenvb: Thanks for your note! For my purpose, this is ok. But is there a more general way to do it (which I'd also prefer)?

Comment: Qmake does not expose such functionality, so no, there is nothing more general.

Answer (score 1):

`QMAKE_CFLAGS` is used only in `qmake.conf`. If you want to have it for specific `.pro`, use `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` flag:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -include header.h
```

Comment: In my case, there's no qmake.conf, but QtCreator's <Project>.pro file, which I think is the right place to set the QMAKE_CFLAGS. I already tried this, without success.

Comment: `qmake.conf` is for systemwide settings, not project specific settings.

Comment: @rubenvb _global preinclude ... for every c-file_ - this is how I understood the question.

Comment: @svlasov yeah, for a [single] Qt Creator project.